# InstallShield Standalone 2015 builder crash

Tags: installshield

I have upgraded InstallShield 2013 to 2015 and now when I’m building one .ism with InstallShield 2015 Standalone build the action stopped at the middle without any error message or known reason.

That’s the command I’m running:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015 SAB\System\IsCmdBld.exe" -p D:\temp.ism -r RELEASE_1 -a RELEASE_1 -b C:\Release\ISDEV -x -z ProductBuild=01
```

This is the output:

```
Dialog SetupResume for language English (United States) built
Dialog SetupType for language English (United States) built
Dialog SplashBitmap for language English (United States) built
Resolving strings...
Language English (United States) built

C:\>
```

Any idea what can cause this ?
It seems other projects I have converted to ISH 2015 are built fine so I guess it specific to this ism project.
Also I don’t have problem building the setup with InstallShield IDE on other machine I have.

Comment: Try adding `-v` to your command line to get more verbose output. It may help to highlight more closely where things are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I added -v to the command and now I see the the files copy from source to setup locations just stopped.                                             Copying from "I:\bin\AAA.dll" to "C:\Release\ISDEV\...\program files\bin\AAA.dll"

C:\>

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield support tried to help me with this but with no luck,
it seems to be like a specific problem on my machine.
After reinstalling entire machine ( due to disk failure ) I no longer have this problem.